# assign a domain name to ec2 instance w/o elastic IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2, dns, amazon-route53

I registered a domain name with `AWS Route 53` as `mydomain.com`. Is there anyway that I can assign e.g. `ns1.mydomain.com` as a public hostname to an `EC2` which does **NOT** have a `Elasti IP`?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign the domain name to any IP address of an instance. However be aware of the following limitations:

- If a domain name is assigned to a private IP, it will not be connectable without network access to that IP
- If the domain is assigned to a non-elastic public IP if the instance stops and starts you would lose the public IP so would need to update the DNS resolution.

If you have a public facing application, but want to keep network traffic that directly connects to the instance private you should look at using an ELB in front of the application to provide a security boundary between the internet and your application.

Comment: Thanks. That's correct. The problem is that I do not have any elastic IP left.

Comment: You can ask AWS support for an increase @Rebecca :)

Answer (score 1):

- Utilize a load balancer in front of the instance and assign the public hostname to the load balancer.
- Use [S3 webpage redirect](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/how-to-page-redirect.html) and assign the hostname to the S3 URI.

If the problems is that you don't have any elastic IP's left, you can [request](https://console.aws.amazon.com/support/home#case/create?issueType=service-limit-increase&limitType=service-code-elastic-ips-ec2-classic&serviceLimitIncreaseType=elastic-ips&type=service_limit_increase) for more. This should be resolved within about 15 minutes.